# Refer to values in JSS theme in the theme it self

Tags: reactjs, jss

I’m using jss through react-jss. 
Let’s say that I have a theme where I have defined a base color. Then I want to define a default border in this theme, referring to the base color.

```
const theme = {
  baseColor: ‘#aaaaaa’,
  defaultBorder: [[1, ‘solid’, this.baseColor]]
}
```

I haven’t found a syntax for this. Isn’t it possible? Do I have to define the color outside and use it both places?

```
const baseColor = ‘#aaaaaa’;
const theme = {
  baseColor: baseColor,
  defaultBorder: [[1, ‘solid’, baseColor]]
}
```

Comment: Can't you just use `theme.baseColor` ? Maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: nope, you can't. theme is the constant being defined, so trying to refer to it directly ends up in a 'undefined' error.

Comment: You could define you theme in a module and import it in whatever component you like then.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing. The question is how to best define the theme itself - if it is possible to reuse part of he theme definition in the theme it self.

Comment: Oh I just understood :p I'll edit my answer then!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it. There maybe a better solution though.

mytheme.js :

```
export const baseColor = '#aaa'

const theme = {
  baseColor,
  defaultBorder: [[1, 'solid', baseColor]]
}

export default theme
```

The advantages I see in this are the following:

- Your theme will be "auto documented" as the project grows and easily
  updatable.
- Exporting each constant like `export const baseColor =
  '#aaa'` also makes your theme constants useable in the components if
  needed.
- You could implement multiple themes based on just the
  constants having a object structure "convention" with a little 
  modifications on the structure of the theme files.

Comment: Yes, this is the way I ask if is the only way in the question.

Comment: By my "not extensive at all" knowledge, it is. But I see a good thing in this: Your theme will be "auto documented" as the project grows and easily updatable. Exporting each constant like `export const baseColor = '#aaa'` also makes your theme constants useable in the components if needed. So I think this is not bad at all!

Comment: I'll rather have my components access those values through the theme, though. That's kinda the reason for having a theme in the first place. If the other constants are exposed and used, switching theme will have no effect.

Comment: I'm sorry I could not help you then. I'll still follow this thread as I'm curious if there's a solution suitable for your needs !

Comment: Your attempt is appreciated ;-)  I'm letting the question stay in case a jss guru passes by.

Answer (score 0):

It is basically a JavaScript question, not a JSS one. You can put it in a separate variable like you suggested. In order to use "this" you need to create a class.

So I would also recommend putting reusable stuff in separate variables or even into a separate object and if it grows even export it from a separate module.

Comment: The use of ‘this’ is of cause a js issue, but jss has a lot of nifty syntax that is taken into account when generating the final css, like @ and & and ‘extend’ and what not, so there could be that it had something allowing to refer to other rules defines in the theme.